# Searching array field in JPARepository

Tags: java, spring, postgresql

I have a **PostgreSQL** table where `channel_ids` field is BIGINT[].
In console I can search like so:

```
select * FROM user where 10000=ANY(channel_ids).
```

But I can't figure out how to build up the Specification for search in `JpaRepository`.

```java
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    Page<User> findAll(Specification<User> spec, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Is it even supported?

Comment: Seems you have to use a collection I believe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22935278/is-it-possible-to-use-an-array-object-as-a-parameter-in-spring-repository-query?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: This one seems different as he wants to search by some value in array, i.e. id in (1000,10001). I need the opposite 10000= ANY(ids)

Comment: I know but I just meant that you have to use a collection.

Comment: Why not do a select on channel table to match the user and the id you wanted?